# libgdx 3D game engine for Android

Tags: android, libgdx

I want to build a 3D game using libGDX game engine. I don't know how to use libGDX. Can anyone help me how to use libGDX to create a 3D game? Any sample code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check libGDX wiki page for great tutorials!! It even contain a small game example :)

http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/TableOfContents?tm=6

Comment: but there's no anything about 3D! :)

Answer (score 3):

Besides the wiki page which is great for the begining i would recommend to take a look here

Demos :
https://github.com/badlogic/libgdx/tree/master/demos

Tests:
http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Ftests%2Fgdx-tests%2Fsrc%2Fcom%2Fbadlogic%2Fgdx%2Ftests

it might take time but you can learn a lot from these resources